# RemoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity not working with Android Wear OS 4 Emulator

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I am developing a companion app for my Android Wear OS watch face. I am trying to use the `startRemoteActivity` method to launch Google Play store an a watch, where a user can download the watch face (a pretty typical thing for a watch face companion app to do).

However, calling `startRemoteActivity` method to open the store on a Wear OS 4 emulator does not work (it works okay in combination with a Wear OS 3 emulator and a physical device). It does not throw any exception, it just does not execute anything. The call of the function simply never completes, code execution gets stuck forever on the `startRemoteActivity` line. Below, you can see my code, but I doubt anything is wrong with it (continue reading, to see why I think so).

I installed 3rd party watch face companion apps on my phone and they also do not seem to work with the Wear OS 4 emulator. They detect the connected/paired watch (same as my companion app) but then when it's time to start a remote activity (typically to open a Google Play store), nothing happens (again, same as in my app).

Has anyone else noticed anything similar? Does `startRemoteActivity` method of the `RemoteActivityHelper` work for you guys in combination with the Wear OS 4 emulator?

I have the latest macOS Hedgehog version of Android Studio installed, along with the latest Emulator, tools, and whatnot.

```
            val connectedNodes = nodeClient.connectedNodes.await()
            if (connectedNodes.isEmpty())
                return false

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                .setData(Uri.parse(storeLink))

            var startedStoreOnAtLeastOneDevice = false
            var atLeastOneNodeReportedAnError = false

            for (node in connectedNodes) {
                try {
                    remoteActivityHelper
                        .startRemoteActivity(
                            targetIntent = intent,
                            targetNodeId = node.id
                        ).await()

                    startedStoreOnAtLeastOneDevice = true
                } catch (t: Throwable) {
                    atLeastOneNodeReportedAnError = true
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. If anyone else stumbles across the same issue, upgrading "Wear OS by Google" app in the emulator solves the problem. Here are the steps:

1. Open `Play Store` app on the Wear OS 4 emulator.
2. Scroll all the way down and select the `Manage apps` option (2nd from the bottom).
3. Install all available updates (in my case, the emulator had 6 pending updates, "Wear OS by Google" being the important one).